# Matplotlib - bar chart starts does not start with 0

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a data and I am looking to present it in bar chart form.

data:

```
col1 = ['2018 01 01', '2018 01 02', '2018 12 27'] #dates
col2 = ['4554', '14120', '1422'] #usage of the user in seconds for that data in col1
```

my code:

I have imported all of the modules

```
import openpyxl as ol
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(col1, col2, label="Usage of the user")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Usage in seconds")
plt.title('Usage report of ' + str(args.user))
plt.legend()
plt.savefig("data.png")
```

When I open data.png
I get this:

[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWS8J.png)

The graph looks all over the place, I want it to start at zero.

I am new to the matplotlib and openpyxl.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A suggestion: convert the dates to actual dates and the strings to numbers. If you have timeseries data look at pandas.

Comment: Do you want it to start at `"zero"`, `"0"` or `0`?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the issue is that the values in `col2` that are being plotted on the y-axis are strings rather than integers. Updating these values to integers will allow the y-axis to start at `0` and be in sequential order.

```
col1 = ['2018 01 01', '2018 01 02', '2018 12 27'] #dates
col2 = ['4554', '14120', '1422']

plt.bar(col1, [int(x) for x in col2], label="Usage of the user")
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Usage in seconds")
plt.title('Usage report')
plt.legend()
```

[image]