# How to change y-axis limits on a bar graph?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, axis

I have a `df`, from which Ive indexed `europe_n` and Ive plotted a bar plot.

- `europe_n` *(r=5, c=45)*, looks like this. ;
  [image]
- `df['Country']`(*string*) & `df['Population']`(*numeric*) variable/s.

```py
plt.bar(df['Country'],df['Population'], label='Population')
plt.xlabel('Country')  
plt.ylabel('Population')  
plt.legend()  
plt.show()
```

Which gives me;

[image]

**Objective:** Im trying to change my y-axis limit to start from **0**, instead of **43,094**.
I ran the, `plt.ylim(0,500000)` method, but there was no change to the y-axis and threw an error. Any suggestions from matplotlib library?

**Error**;
[image]

**Conclusion:** The reason why I wasn't able to plot the graph as I wanted was due to all columns being in `object` dtype. I only realized this when Jupyter threw an error stating, 'there are no integers to plot'. Eventually converted the digit column `Population` to `int` type, code worked and I got the graph!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Yaxis in Matplotlib using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787366/setting-yaxis-in-matplotlib-using-pandas)

Comment: Did you run plt.ylim before displaying the figure? It needs to be in the same code block

Comment: No its all in the same block. Ive now ran the plt.set_ylim. And throws an error, 'matplotlib.pyplot has no attribute 'set_ylim'.

Comment: That’s true - it doesn’t. Axes objects have set_ylim, plt just has ylim. So you need to get the axis object as indicated in that answer.

Comment: You call plt.ylim before plt.show? Can you post your code and errors in the question? It’s hard for us to debug the code you don’t show us ;)

Comment: I dont understand, what do you mean by 'So you need to get the axis object as indicated in that answer'. Could you please show me? : )

Comment: Ive also updated the question with the errors.

Comment: this is a duplicated question. please see the answer I linked to. `ax = df.plot(...); ax.set_ylim(0, 500000)` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Neither of these suggestions seem to work.

Comment: please note there is a difference between `plt` and `ax`. There is no method `plt.set_ylim`. You can't call this. But you can call `ax.set_ylim` using the axis object you define in the line above. If things "don't work" you need to update your question to include the code and the full traceback. Also, [please don't post images of code, data, or errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/) - instead, copy and paste them as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax.set_ylim([0,max_value])`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Country':['Denmark', 'Finland', 'Iceland', 'Norway', 'Sweden'],
    'Population':[5882261, 5540745, 372899, 5434319, 10549347]
})
print(df)
###
   Country  Population
0  Denmark     5882261
1  Finland     5540745
2  Iceland      372899
3   Norway     5434319
4   Sweden    10549347
```

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df['Country'], df['Population'], color='#3B4B59')
ax.set_title('Population of Countries')
ax.set_xlabel('Country')
ax.set_ylabel('Population')
max_value = 12000000
ticks_loc = np.arange(0, max_value, step=2000000)
ax.set_yticks(ticks_loc)
ax.set_ylim([0,max_value])
ax.set_yticklabels(['{:,.0f}'.format(x) for x in ax.get_yticks()])
ax.grid(False)
fig.set_size_inches(10,5)
fig.set_dpi(300)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Be sure that you already imported the following packages,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Your code should probably like:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(europe_n['Country'].values, europe_n['Area(sq km)'].values, color='#3B4B59')
ax.set_xlabel('Country')
ax.set_ylabel('Population')
max_value = 500000
ticks_loc = np.arange(0, max_value, step=10000)
ax.set_yticks(ticks_loc)
ax.set_ylim(0,max_value)
ax.set_yticklabels(['{:,.0f}'.format(x) for x in ax.get_yticks()])
ax.grid(False)
fig.set_size_inches(10,5)
fig.set_dpi(300)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Copied the entire block. I get the everything in the graph above, except the black bars :D
Any ideas?

Comment: Is your `df`'s format like mine? You know, simply `Country`, and `Population`, maybe upper/lower case?

Comment: I've updated the post, now you can take the `df` as an example to give a try.

Comment: You may adjust the `max_value`, and `step` to fit your expectation.

Comment: What I did was, from my original df, I indexed, ```europe_n = df[(df['Country']=='Sweden')|(df['Country']=='Norway')|(df['Country']=='Denmark')|(df['Country']=='Finland')| (df['Country']=='Iceland')]```

You see this code, in my error picture that Ive added in my question. Didnt work. I copied your df and it works. 

Question is, why doesnt it work on my original indexed df? What are the formats and how do we check this?

Comment: Could you edit your post to show what exactly `europe_n` looks like? I wanna see the structure of it.

Comment: In your original post, it's not `plt.set_ylim(0,500000)`, it should be modified to `ax.set_ylim(0,500000)`

Comment: Done. Take a look.

Comment: I've updated the post, please check the code I suggested beneath.

Comment: I still get the same result as before, everything except the bars. It's super strange, why indexed rows dont display.

Comment: Try again, updated again but please restart the kernal and clear output first, I was worried that you probabily touched function `plt`, after you create `europe_n`, then run the code I gave you, this time use `europe_n['Country'].values, europe_n['Area(sq km)'].values`, and perhaps you could try all of this in **Colab**.

Comment: I figured out why it wasn't working and I'd apologies foremost. All columns were as object data type. I changed the 'Population' to int type and it worked! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html

#### To set the y limit

plt.ylim(start,end)

#### To set the x limit

plt.xlim(start,end)

**Example**
[image]

Comment: The graph gets ruined. Doesnt work.

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Take a look at the picture above, I get the same error.

Comment: Well yeah thats the issue. It didnt produce the graphs at all. Its very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that values being plotted on the y-axis are strings rather than integers. You need to convert the values to integer and it will solve the problem. In your case `population` array needs to get updated:

```
Country = ['India', 'US', 'UK']
population = ['4554', '14120', '1422']

plt.bar(Country , [int(x) for x in population], label="Usage of the population")
plt.xlabel("Countries")
plt.ylabel("Population values")
plt.title('Population report')
plt.legend()
```

There is detailed answer:
[Matplotlib - bar chart starts does not start with 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254375/matplotlib-bar-chart-starts-does-not-start-with-0)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34510189)